# New Google Plus Comments in Blog - How to View / Receive Notifications?

Tags: comments, google-plus, blogger

I have a Blogger blog and I used to have Blogger's own comment system in it. I didn't like some parts of it, so I tried changing to Google+ comments instead.

I have no problems with the comment box, it's implemented well, works fine, etc. But when I had Blogger comments, I could see the newest comments my visitors had posted site-wide and I also received email notifications when someone posted a comment in any post of my blog.

However, now, with Google Plus comments, I don't seem to get any sort of notification. (no emails, not even that alert thingy on top-right corner of Google that only ever shows Youtube comments I don't care about) And, also, I know of no way to check the most recent comment in my website.

I kind of need either of these features (most recent / notifications) so I can reply to people when they post comments on my blog. After all I got dozens of posts it's not viable to check every single one of them for new comments every single day.

How can I view the most recent Google plus comments within a website? Or at least receive an email when there is a new Google plus comment posted in my website?

P.S.: I'm not interested in an API for these. There should be an actual user interface somewhere for these things, right?

Comment: There was a notification feature which they were in the process of  implementing back in November 2013 for comments received via Google+ on Blogger(You can check the screenshots for the same in this thread - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50879/i-cant-see-the-comments-on-my-blogger-posts/51846 ) but it was likely dropped midway

Comment: @PrayagVerma Oh... but what about non-blogger sites? How do they view their newest comments / get notified? Maybe I can do like them?

Comment: After researching around, I found that this feature has broken down many times in the past. It last worked correctly until October 2016. I found a recent  forum thread - https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/5tmmH6XaA_Q/YvMlYKuuBQAJ in which a Google Employee has escalated this issue to the concerned team around a month back (2nd Feb) but there seems to be have been no progress on it.Regarding non-Blogger sites using Google+ comments,Google never really rolled out this feature officially outside Blogger,users started using it by getting the code from how it was implemented on Blogger.

Comment: @PrayagVerma welp, that really sucks. Thanks for the info. I guess I'll stop using google+ comments, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently stands, this feature has not worked since October 2016.

According to a [post by a Google Employee](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/5tmmH6XaA_Q/YvMlYKuuBQAJ) in the official Blogger Forum on 2nd February 2017 -

> Hi all,
>
> Thanks for posting.
>
> Just wanted to let you know that the concerned team is aware of this
>   issue and is working on it. I will keep you all posted as soon as I
>   get an update from them.
>
> Best,
>
> Theo

Any updates regarding this issue will be likely posted in the above forum thread